# Can't go to external urls using either href or ng-href

Tags: html, redirect, href

I'm trying to have a dynamic URL that takes the user to an external website with AngularJS. However the link takes the user to a route on my page when clicked.

For example, if my url is "mysite.com", and my link is "google.com". If I click on this link, using either `href` or `ng-href`, it takes me to a non-existent route on my site: "mysite.com/google.com"

How can I navigate to external URLs?

A sample of my code:

```
<a href="{{ linkItem.link }}" target="_blank">View file</a>
```

Whereas `linkItem.link` is "google.com". This doesn't work as expected for any webpage, even for the ones that have hard coded href attributes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is caused by not having a protocol (ie. `http://` or `https://`) prefixed in the URL which makes the browser think it's a relative path. There are two ways to fix it:

1. Require the user to input a valid URL with `http://` or `https://` at the beginning.
2. Create a filter or directive that adds the prefix if it's missing.

Comment: I would add that this has nothing to do with Angular. That's how the `href` attribute has worked for over 20 years.

Comment: What do you mean by 'create a filter'?

Comment: @sherrellbc, AngularJS had [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter), the Angular equivalent would be [pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)