# My HTML link is not redirecting to another website (cpanel hosting)

Tags: html, cpanel

I have a personal website and I am trying to have an image and upon clicking, redirect to another website. My own website is for instance www.example.com, and I want to (upon clicking image) go to www.website.com. However, it goes to www.example.com/www.website.com and I do not want that. The code looks alright:

```
 <a href="www.website.com">
   <br><img src="website.png" alt="Avatar" class="webimage">
 </a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need the absolute link to the site, so: `https://www.website.com/`, without the http or https part, it will think it's a relative URL.

Comment: I found a not-so great dupe; Possible duplicate of [Can't go to external urls using either href or ng-href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601396/cant-go-to-external-urls-using-either-href-or-ng-href)

Comment: @abccd Yeah, you need to include the protocol. Without it, it’s interpreted as a relative URL path, and no slash is equivalent to `./`, which means this should be appended to the current directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. You have to use http:// or https:// in front of the link. Otherwise it will redirect you to a local path.

```html
 <a href="http://www.website.com">
   <br><img src="website.png" alt="Avatar" class="webimage">
 </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Relative URL paths are any without a protocol, delimited by `//`. It could begin `http://`, `https://`, or even simply `//` (though the delimiter without a stated protocol can apparently be used as an attack vector and so should be avoided.

Relative URLs with `./` or no slash are appended to the current directory. Those with `../` go up one to the parent directory. And those with a single slash (`/`) go to the site root.

Since you’re already at site root, that is your current directory, so the address is appended there.